# Aligning textview through android java

Tags: java, android

At the moment everything is done through the java code. I'm creating a relative layout then adding my GL surface view and some text views to it. the problem is I cant align one text view to the top left and the other to the top right. Whats wrong with my code. Also is there a more efficient way of doing this such as doing this through XML instead. Cause I've tried this and it didn't work.

```
    r1 = new RelativeLayout(this);
    view = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    view.setKeepScreenOn(true);//keeps activity from going to sleep

    r1.addView(view);
    TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
    TextView text2 = new TextView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 200);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    text1.setLayoutParams(lp);
    text1.setText("3 Star");
    text1.setBackgroundColor(0x4060ff70);
    rp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
    text2.setLayoutParams(rp);
    text2.setText("4 Star");
    text1.setTextSize(30);
    text2.setTextSize(30);
    //text2.setBackgroundColor(0x4060ff70);
    r1.addView(text1);
    r1.addView(text2);

    setContentView(r1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in XML like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what about the java code. How should i change that so it references this xml file

Comment: Put the XML file in res/layout. Then `setContentView(R.layout.filename);`